# Javascript post to php and failed to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, xmlhttprequest

I intended to make a dynamic website which provide vocab quiz.
I modified some of the w3school examples but it didn't work.

```
<?php 

?>

<script>
//var vocabid;
var ans;
function getnumber(str)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getnumber.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}


function getvocab(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("vocab").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getvocab.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function getpart(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("part").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getpart.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function getchi(str)
{
var inner_ans
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    inner_ans=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getchi.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
return inner_ans;
}



function loadvocab()
{
//vocabid=Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
vocabid=getnumber();
//vocabid= document.getElementById("num_result").value;
getvocab(vocabid);
getpart(document.getElementById("num_result").value);
var ans=getchi(vocabid);
//document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = document.getElementById("num_result").value;
//document.write(document.getElementById("num_box").value;);
//document.write(ans);
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div name="vocab" style="width:300px; top:10px ; background-color:rgb(255,0,255);display:inline-block; position:relative;">
vocab
<span id="vocab"></span>
</div>
<div name="part" style="width:100px;position:relative;background-color:rgb(255,0,255);display:inline-block;">
pt. of speech
<span id="part"></span>
</div>
<div name="chi" style="width:100px;position:relative;background-color:rgb(255,0,255);display:inline-block;">
chi
<span id="chi"></span>
</div>
<br>
<div name="ans_box" style="width:100px;position:relative;background-color:rgb(255,0,255);display:inline-block;top:100px;">
<form name="ans">
<input type="text" name="ans_text">
</form>
<span id="number"></span>
</div>
<div name="check" style="width:300px;left:10px; top:100px ; background-color:rgb(255,0,255);display:inline-block; position:relative;" onclick="check_vocab(document.ans.ans_text.value)">
check
<span id="check"></span>
</div>
<font  id="num"></font>
<div name="next" style="width:100px;left:10px;position:relative;background-color:rgb(255,0,255);display:inline-block;top:100px; " onclick="loadvocab();">
next
</div>
<div  style="width:100px;left:10px;position:relative;background-color:rgb(255,0,255);display:inline-block;top:100px;">
<form name="result">
<span id="txtHint"></span>
<input type="button" onclick=" getpart(1);">
<input type="button" onclick=" getvocab(1);">

<input type="button" onclick=" getchi(1);">
</form>
</div>
<div id="num_box">



</div>
```

when the "next" div is clicked, it goes through a number of js functions and fetch new words form the access file.
but the first one, which will generate a random number at the php, failed to get back, the variable just contain "undefined".
but as u can see, it works alone with the buttons.

later on i tried to but the variable in a textbox and get it with js, but it take 2 clicks to return the data to the "span"tag.

can u guys help to figure it out what happened, or give suggestions to me?

edit: do the soultion support unicode? coz i have some unicode characters in the db.

Comment: Please post the code here, or at least the important parts to it. There is no guarantee that the code will exist at the link forever, and the link will be meaningless then.

Comment: The code sample is the barebones method of using ajax. Is there any reason you cannot use a library (for example jquery) that makes this easier.

Comment: Can you generally explain how to use jquery to do this? Sorry for being noob at js.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/

Comment: thanks. Solved using ajax + jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. When you call getNumber function, the browser calls the server and wait for a response. Meanwhile, browser goes on to do stuff and uses an undefined variable (vocabid, because the server hasn't answered yet).
You need to implement callback on you ajax call.

Example:

```
// declare getnumber
function getnumber(okfn) {
    // do ajax call and write an onreadystatechange function like this:
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            okfn(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
}
// use getnumber
getnumber(function(resp) {
    getvocab(resp);
});
```

getvocab and the other function with ajax call are async too, so you need to use callback again.